# Click to move should i verify by tag or by game object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Recently i came across developing a RPG game as diablo and basically the movement control needs to be carefuly made and verify every element we click before move. I was wondering by having alot of prefab of enemy gameobject, the UI and myself if i must verify by the elements with the tag i want or by the gameobject.
Well for example if i have all UI gameobjects with tag UI and enemys with tag enemy, is it good to verify by tag instead of verying directly by the gameobject name? I'm quite confused with i should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how many GameObjects you are verifying and how often you do it. If you don't this every frame or very often then don't worry about it. If you do it every frame or very often then check the GameObject by `tag` instead of by `name` but make sure to use the [`GameObject.CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html) function to do so not with the [`GameObject.tag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-tag.html) variable.

The reason is because [`GameObject.name`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-name.html) and [`GameObject.tag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-tag.html) allocates memory.  [`GameObject.CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html) does not.

Comment: thanks alot, well i'm running it in an update ofc because i need to know in each frame what player is doing in my movement script because with that i can define if he is idle or moving. I just need to block the elements than that has the tag UI because i'm adding more eles so if i add the tag to the new ones, i dont need to add extra code. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, no extra code when you add tag. Just check it with `CompareTag`

Comment: Thanks once again, it may be dumb questions but i also like to be sure of before starting making extra code for nothing.

Comment: It's not a dumb question.  I've seen people confused on which one to use including me too then ran a test and CompareTag won

Comment: Well i'm not confused about what i need to use, just about optimization and reducing work and now i've seen that comparetag will check every gameobject with the tag i give as parameter and not only gameobject name which is good and will help me alot in the case of enemys or UI elements

Comment: Np. You can also check with layer but that's not important but tag should be used as layers are used for special stuff like blocking collision. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on this subject